# How to create basic IFC File in C#

Tags: c#, ifc, xbim

As per Wiki, The Industry Foundation Classes (IFC) data model is intended to describe architectural, building and construction industry data.

The Industry Foundation Classes (IFC) data model is a neutral and open specification that is not controlled by a single vendor or group of vendors. It is an object oriented file format with a data model developed by buildingSMART (International Alliance for Interoperability, IAI) to facilitate interoperability in the building industry, and is a commonly used format for Building Information Modeling (BIM).

For example One could be developing virtual building model in Revit, then send it to interior team who use ArchiCAD. It might also be sent to engineers who use Tekla. Before the IFC standard file type this would have been a nightmare. As Revit, ArchiCAD, Tekla can talk to each other, but not easily!!!

IFC aims to solve this problem, so that it won't matter so much. IFC file is unified format which can be understood by other CAD Softwares as well.

My Organisation works on one of the CAD Software and they want to export there Models in IFC so that it can be open and viewed in Other software's as well like Revit, ArchiCAD, Tekla.

So Our use case is, we need to create a IFC file of such a model.

So as per this Post, I am planning to use xBim. This link

I am using xBim Library to Create IFC File in C#. As per xBim documentation and Sample Code, I found that, How to create a Simple wall.

Now I want to create a basic Xbim.Ifc4.HvacDomain.IfcPump.

Can someone help me how to create one Xbim.Ifc4.HvacDomain.IfcPump in IFC using xBim C#?

I am new in CAD development and hence I am finding difficulties to understand the IFC. Please do the needful.

I hope this much information will be helpful,enough and clear.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of code of what have you tried is difficult to help, but you can find resources in the [API of XBim](http://docs.xbim.net/XbimDocs/html/161ebabf-e891-82c9-89e4-0ccea0a09db5.htm). With the examples of how to setup a wall in the document and the API documentation you should have clues to how to start your program, once you have some code, you can clarify the question so the community can help you more efficiently.

About how the IFC works and is written, you can find all you need to know [here](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC4_2/FINAL/HTML/) if you use a different version check the [this website](https://technical.buildingsmart.org/standards/ifc/ifc-schema-specifications/), in the IFC documentation the pump you are looking for is [here](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC4_2/FINAL/HTML/).

I hope this resources are useful for you task.